# Is any information given to the backstory, origin and abilities of Hancock?

Tags: hancock

*[Hancock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hancock_(film))* is a 2010 superhero dramedey film starring Will Smith as the titular hero. It's a deconstruction of sorts, showing what could happen if a being of incredible power was less responsible, upstanding citizen or protector seeking redemption, and more of a moody, troubled, apathetic human with a chip on his shoulder... basically, your average a**hole (but *don't* call him that!)

In the story, we learn Hancock is basically immortal, indestructible (save for hangovers) and ageless, with keen senses, strength to move mountains and the ability to fly. Charlize Theron plays his counterpart, with the same abilities and also some limited weather manipulation. By her words, they have always existed, being called different things: "Gods, Angels....now suddenly it's *super hero*." She says that, whatever they are, they were "created in pairs", with a natural, almost irresistible pull to find each other. When they are around each other long enough, they start to lose their abilities and become mortal to love and procreate, which explains why they are the last. Hancock, however, was made stronger than the others, "to protect."

And... that's about it.

No other real history is provided; they are just "here" and *always* have been. Even the full extent of their abilities is never made clear in the film.

I'm curious to know **if there is any deeper, canonical information on their origins and abilities.**

Answer (score 2):

It was based on a previous script called *[Tonight, He Comes](http://www.hollywood-elsewhere.com/images/column/7108/tonight.pdf)*. There's even less backstory there, if you can imagine that.

Comment: Thank you, Nate. I'll check it out.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question asked. Can you elaborate on what info is provided by the spec script.